# How can I make use of dictionary in order to store multiple values in two different arrays

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I want to store values of last traded price for the derivative quote of INFOSYS and RELIANCE in two different lists. After that, I want my program to subtract the two latest values from the respective list and provide the output as a difference between the values. The given code provides output for one derivative quote.

How can use the single code to provide me the desired output from multiple lists? Can I make use of a dictionary to solve the problem?

```
import requests
import json
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import datetime, threading


LTP_arr=[0]
url = 'https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=INFY&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=27JUN2019&type=-&strike=-'

def ltpwap():
    resp = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(resp.content, 'lxml')
    data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#responseDiv').text.strip())

    LTP=data['data'][0]['lastPrice']
    n2=float(LTP.replace(',', ''))

    LTP_arr.append(n2)
    LTP1= LTP_arr[-1] - LTP_arr[-2]

    print("Difference between the latest two values of INFY is ",LTP1)
    threading.Timer(1, ltpwap).start()

ltpwap()
```

Which produces:

```
Difference between the latest two values of INFY is 4.
```

The expected outcome is:

```
INFY_list = (729, 730, 731, 732, 733)
RELIANCE_list = (1330, 1331, 1332, 1333, 1334)
```

Comment: I can't follow the question at all. Please provide the expected outcome

Comment: How can I store values of multiple scrips in different multiple lists

Comment: Expected outcome: INFY_list=(729,730,731,732,733)  RELIANCE_list=(1330,1331,1332,1333,1334)

Comment: Please do not post code in comments, [edit] your question instead

Comment: How can I make use of dictionary to store the values in two different lists that contain the last price of the scrip which changes dynamically?

Comment: Your code does HTTP GET to a web site, extracts a number from it and store it in a list. It does this activity every 1 sec. Can you explain what is `INFY_list ` and `RELIANCE_list `

Comment: @balderman INFY_list and RELIANCE_list are names of the list where I am storing extracted values.

Comment: @AdityaTaide OK - Can you please try to explain what is wrong with the current code? What are you looking for?

Comment: @ balderman If I want maintain the values for n number of list, I have to write the same code n number of times, here I mentioned only two lists. So I am looking at how can I reduce the number of lines of code by using some loop or maybe some dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach than keep some lists is just make generators that produces desired value from URLs at some interval. Here is implementation with `time.sleep()` but with many URLs I would suggest to look at `asyncio`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import requests
from collections import defaultdict
from time import sleep

urls_to_watch = {
    'INFOSYS': 'https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=INFY&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=27JUN2019&type=-&strike=-',
    'RELIANCE': 'https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=RELIANCE&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=27JUN2019&type=-&strike=-'
}

def get_values(urls):
    for name, url in urls.items():
        resp = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs(resp.content, 'lxml')
        data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#responseDiv').text.strip())

        LTP=data['data'][0]['lastPrice']
        n2=float(LTP.replace(',', ''))
        yield name, n2

def check_changes(urls):
    last_values = defaultdict(int)
    current_values = {}
    while True:
        current_values = dict(get_values(urls))
        for name in urls.keys():
            if current_values[name] - last_values[name]:
                yield name, current_values[name], last_values[name]
        last_values = current_values
        sleep(1)

for name, current, last in check_changes(urls_to_watch):
    # here you can just print the values, or store current value to list
    # and periodically store it to DB, etc.
    print(name, current, last, current - last)
```

Prints:

```
INFOSYS 750.7 0 750.7
RELIANCE 1284.4 0 1284.4
RELIANCE 1284.8 1284.4 0.3999999999998636
INFOSYS 749.8 750.7 -0.900000000000091
RELIANCE 1285.4 1284.8 0.6000000000001364

...and waits infinitely for any change to occur, then prints it.
```